# Split comma separated column into rows - For Multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, regexp-substr

I have to split the declared string delimited by ; into rows as below. It works well if I declare the string and split it. Instead of declaring, I  have to select this string from a table and parse it repeatedly. Each row can contain different number of strings.

What would be the best approach?? Should I loop through each row, parse them or is there a better way of doing it??

--Required output

```
status := off
status:= on
```

--QUERY

```
declare
myString varchar2(2000):='status := off; status:= on;';
begin
     for r in
      ( select regexp_substr(myString,'[^;]+',1,level) element
          from dual
       connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(myString,'[^;]+')) + 1
      )
      loop
       dbms_output.put_line(r.element);
     end loop;
   end;
```

Comment: It looks like this might be a question about Oracle? You may wish to [edit] your question and add `sql` and `oracle` to your question to get the question in front of the right audience.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica It is a dupe, there are plenty of questions on splitting delimited strings in Oracle; if you wish to find a better duplicate then please add/edit the list of duplicates. I've already added a second duplicate on splitting from a table and am looking for more. You have the reputation to do the same. Also, the OP does not rule out a variable in PL/SQL they are asking for opinions on a "best" way to do it.... so even if it is not a duplicate (it is) then it should be closed as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

There's really not much difference - you select from your table instead of DUAL, using the appropriate column instead `myString`:

```
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(A_STRING,'[^;]+',1,LEVEL)) ELEMENT
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(A_STRING,'[^;]+')) + 1
```

I tossed a `TRIM` in there because the second row had an extra blank in front of it. Leave in or remove at our option.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fc6a5b73093759f3270c79b80d164a4f)

Comment: Thank you. When I try to do a select as specified, it never pulls any rows. I changed the connect by level > 0 and it threw a "not enough memory for connect by operation" message.

Comment: `LEVEL` is always > 0, so `CONNECT BY LEVEL > 0` is basically an infinite loop. OK, simplify. What happens if you do `SELECT whatever FROM YOUR_TABLE`? If that produces data, then start adding elements until things break. Then figure out why it broke.